# No me actualiza los campos

Tags: python, django

tengo un problema para actualizar mi campo status, lo que trato de hacer es comparar el campo referencia_p de la tabla list_planillas y el campo referencia_bnc de la tabla banco_bnc, y si lo campos son iguales entoces deberia de actualizar el campo status de NO COMPROBADO A COMPROBADO, pero no me actualiza

model.py:

```
class list_planillas(models.Model):
     codigo_p= models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
     modalidad = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
     referencia_p = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
     banco = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
     cuenta = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
     ramo = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
     fecha_p = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
     monto_total = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=False)
     opciones = (
          ('COMPROBADO', 'COMPROBADO'),
          ('NO COMPROBADO', 'NO COMPROBADO'),
          )
     status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=opciones, default='NO COMPROBADO')

class Meta:
    db_table = 'cmp_planillas'

def __str__(self):

    return self.codigo_p

class banco_bnc(models.Model):
     fecha_bnc = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=False, null=True)
     referencia_bnc = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
     monto_bnc = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False,  null=False)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'cmp_bnc'

 def __str__(self):
    return self.referencia_bnc
```

views.py

```
class update_datos(TemplateView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        datos_planillas = list_planillas.objects.all()
        datos_bnc = banco_bnc.objects.all()
                    
       formulario = planillas_form()

       for dta_pla in datos_planillas:
    
          for dta_bnc in datos_bnc:
            if dta_pla.referencia_p == dta_bnc.referencia_bnc:
                if formulario.is_valid():
                    list_planillas.objects.filter(id = dta_pla.pk).update(status = 'COMPROBADO')
                    formulario.save()
            else:
                print(formulario.errors.as_json())

        return redirect('/analisis/')
```

El detalle es que no me genera ningun error y no me imprime ningun error por consola, hasta le pregunte a ChatGpt para ver cual error y solo me dice que compruebe bien los campos que quiero actualizar.